# How to use if control sequence properly

Tags: macros, conditionals, counters, recursion

I don't understand why this code doesn't produce what I describe in the output.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\defaultvalue}{\textit{initialvalue}} %indentation pour les (sous)-questions non-numérotées
\newcommand{\mycounter}{\defaultvalue}
\newcommand{\inmain}{1}

\newcommand{\question}[2][\defaultvalue]{ %Question
        \textbf{Question #1 :} #2
    \ifx\inmain1 \renewcommand{\mycounter}{#1} \fi
}

\begin{document}                                
            mycounter has value \mycounter \\           
            \question[1.a)]{
            \textit{inmain} has value \inmain, therefore I would expect \textit{mycounter} to take value \textit{1.a)} after this.\\
            }
            However, \textit{mycounter} still has value \mycounter
\end{document}
```

[image]

This code was narrowed down so as to only expose the issue I'm facing. However, to anticipate for alternative suggestions, here's the bottom of it just in case it's useful. I'm trying to rewrite a very flexible manual counting system for needs which are irrelevant here. I have a `\question` command and also a `\subquestion` command which calls `\question` (this is useful in case I want to redesign something). These commands have optional arguments which enable manual numbering, and I want the subquestions to optionally carry the number of the main question. Because `\subquestion` calls `\question`, I need a control sequence within `\question` to ensure that the counter isn't changed when `\subquestion` calls `\question`. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have:

`\ifx\inmain1 \renewcommand{\mycounter}{#1} \fi`

With `\ifx` expansion of tokens is not triggered. `\ifx` just compares the meanings of tokens.

`\show\inmain` yields that `\inmain` has the following meaning:

```
> \inmain=\long macro:
->1.
```

`\show1`  yields that `1` has the following meaning:

```
> the character 1.
```

The meanings are **not** equal...

By the way: The reading-apparatus of (La)TeX is in state M (middle of line) after tokenizing the digit-character `1` as an explicit character-token of category-code 12(other). Therefore the space-character behind the `1` gets tokenized as an explicit space-token. (Explicit character-token of category-code 10(space) and character-code 32. 32 is the number of the code-point of the space-character in (La)TeX's internal character-encoding-scheme, which with traditional TeX-engines is ASCII and which with XeTeX- or LuaTeX-based TeX-engines is UTF-8.)

If the condition were true, then that explicit space-token behind the `1` would be delivered as the first token of the "true"-branch. In horizontal mode/non-restricted horizontal mode it would yield horizontal glue which probably is undesired.

The same applies to the space-character behind the closing curly brace/before the `\fi` except that the resulting explicit space-token would be delivered as the last token of the "true"-branch.

Thus the true-branch consists of an explicit space-token, a `\renewcommand`-assignment and another explicit space-token. In horizontal mode/non-restricted horizontal mode both explicit space-tokens would yield horizontal glue.

If you wish to compare two numbers/two TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantities I suggest using `\ifnum`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\defaultvalue}{\textit{initialvalue}} %indentation pour les (sous)-questions non-numérotées
\newcommand{\mycounter}{\defaultvalue}
\newcommand{\inmain}{1}

\newcommand{\question}[2][\defaultvalue]{%
  \textbf{Question #1 :} #2%
  \ifnum\inmain=1 %
    \renewcommand{\mycounter}{#1}%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}                                

mycounter has value \mycounter\\           
\question[1.a)]{%
  \textit{inmain} has value \inmain, therefore I 
   expect \textit{mycounter} to take value
   \textit{1.a)} after this.\\
}%
And voil\`a: \textit{mycounter} has value \mycounter.
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\ifnum\inmain=1 %` two TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantities are compared. When gathering the first token of a TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity  and when gathering more tokens of a TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity that turns out to be a sequence of character-tokens from the set {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0} expansion is not suppressed. Therefore `\inmain` gets expanded when LaTeX starts to gather `\ifnum`'s first TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity. This yields the explicit catcode-12(other)-character-token `1` which will be taken for the first element of a sequence of character-tokens from the set {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}. Then `=` (explicit character-token of catcode 12(other)) is found which terminates the process of gathering more digits that belong to that sequence. The `=` does not get discarded. Then LaTeX starts to gather `\ifnum`'s second TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity. Hereby the space-character behind the `1` also is tokenized as an explicit space-token. But again the character-token `1` is taken for an element/the first element that belongs to a sequence of character-tokens from the set {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}. Thus the space-token is taken for something that terminates the process of gathering more digits that belong to that sequence.
Unlike other tokens that terminate the search for more digits of TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantities that are formed by sequences of character-tokens from the set {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}, e.g., `=`, explicit space-tokens that terminate digit-sequences get discarded silently/get removed from the token-stream.

A remark about how the primitives `\if` and `\ifcat` work:

`\if` does compare character-codes of character-tokens. With `\if` expansion of expandable tokens is triggered before doing the comparison. Non-expandable control sequences which are not implicit character-tokens will all be treated as if they all had the same character-code which differs from all character-codes possible with character-tokens.

`\ifcat` does compare category-codes of character-tokens. With `\ifcat` expansion of expandable tokens is triggered before doing the comparison. Non-expandable control sequences which are not implicit character-tokens will all be treated as if they all had the same category-code which differs from all category-codes possible with character-tokens.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is strange and I don't have much time to explain in details. `\ifx\inmain1` would be true if you did `\let\ifmain1` before, which is not the case (and probably not desirable). `\ifx` doesn't expand what follows. You can use `\ifnum` for integer comparisons; `\ifnum` expands macros when looking for the 〈number〉s (see the TeX grammar).

Since you print the value of `\inmain`, I will first use this technique here. Beware of spurious spaces in your code, but note that the space after `\ifnum\inmain=1` below is on purpose and useful: it terminates the 〈number〉 `1` according to TeX grammar. It doesn't go in the output. It is good practice, but you need to understand why.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\defaultvalue}{\textit{initialvalue}}
\newcommand{\mycounter}{\defaultvalue}
\newcommand{\inmain}{1}

\newcommand{\question}[2][\defaultvalue]{% Question
 \textbf{Question #1 :}~#2%
    \ifnum\inmain=1 \renewcommand{\mycounter}{#1}\fi
}

\begin{document}

mycounter has value \mycounter \\
\question[1.a)]{%
  \textit{inmain} has value \inmain, therefore I would expect
  \textit{mycounter} to take value \textit{1.a)} after this.\\
}
Indeed, \textit{mycounter} has value \mycounter.

\end{document}
```

[image]

A more idiomatic approach is probably to use `\newif\ifinmain` to declare, `\inmaintrue` or `\inmainfalse` to set the flag, and `\ifinmain ... \else ...\fi` to use it (optional `\else`). Also, you are abusing the term counter (I mean, your `\mycounter` macro is not a LaTeX counter) and the line

```latex
\newcommand{\mycounter}{\defaultvalue}
```

probably doesn't do what you want (it stores the control sequence token `\defaultvalue` as the replacement text of macro `\mycounter`; `\mycounter` is *not* expanded at this time). If you define `\defaultvalue` as a number, you probably want something like this:

```latex
\newcommand{\defaultvalue}{3}
\edef\mycounter{\defaultvalue}
```

If you really want formatting commands inside the replacement text of `\defaultvalue`, you could use:

```latex
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\defaultvalue}{\textit{3}}
\protected@edef\mycounter{\defaultvalue}
\makeatother
```

Compiling the last suggestions gives:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\defaultvalue}{\textit{3}}
\protected@edef\mycounter{\defaultvalue}
\newif\ifinmain
\inmaintrue

\newcommand{\question}[2][\defaultvalue]{% Question
 \textbf{Question #1 :}~#2%
    \ifinmain\renewcommand{\mycounter}{#1}\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

mycounter has value \mycounter \\
\question[1.a)]{%
  \texttt{\textbackslash ifinmain} is \texttt{\textbackslash iftrue}, therefore
  \textit{mycounter} will take value \textit{1.a)} after this.\\
}
Indeed, \textit{mycounter} has value \mycounter.

\end{document}
```

[image]

But I repeat, all this looks a bit strange. There may be a better way to do what you need, perhaps with `enumitem`. I fear this is an XY problem.